# Get the colour of a clicked cell table Widget c++

Tags: c++, qtablewidget, qtwidgets

The user colours cells in a table widget as follows:

```cpp
 ui->tableCombat->setItem(0, j, new QTableWidgetItem);
             ui->tableCombat->item(0, j)->setBackground(Qt::black);
```

with J increasing each time the player validates his selection.

Now I would like the player to be able to select cells in this way:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_tableCombat_cellClicked(int row, int column)
{

   if  (Colour of the clicked cell == black)
   {
    Pion1.Movement
    Pion1.Action        
   }
}
```

However, despite a lot of research I can't figure out what I need to write in my if() so that the computer recognises the colour of the cells and compares it to the desired colour...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just from checking on QT documentation turns out there is the function

```
bool QColor::operator==(const QColor &color) const
```

It returns true if this color has the same color specification and component values as color; otherwise returns false.

[Link to more details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#operator-eq-eq)